# How to test two Java concrete children classes that have same behaviors but different implementation details?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, abstract-class

I am thinking about code reuse here:

Assuming we have such classes:

```
 public abstract class AbstractMap {
    public abstract void put(K k, V v);
    public abstract V get(K k);
 }

 public class ConcreteMapA extends AbstractMap {
    @Override
    public void put(K k, V v) {
       // put implementation detail A
       ...
    }
    @Override
    public V get(K k) {
       // get implementation detail A
       ...
    }
 }

 public class ConcreteMapB extends AbstractMap {
    @Override
    public void put(K k, V v) {
       // put implementation detail B
       ...
    }
    @Override
    public V get(K k) {
       // get implementation detail B
       ...
    }
 }
```

The two maps are implementing the same functionalities but with different implementation details. I would like to write unit test for these two concrete classes. But then the test cases start to be duplicate.

```
 public class ConcreteMapATest {
    @Test
    public void testPutCase1 {          
       ...
    }
    @Test
    public void testPutCase2 {          
       ...
    }
    @Test
    public void testGetCase1 {         
       ...
    }
    ...
 }

 // following starts to be duplicate code
 public class ConcreteMapBTest {
    @Test
    public void testPutCase1 {          
       ...
    }
    @Test
    public void testPutCase2 {          
       ...
    }
    @Test
    public void testGetCase1 {         
       ...
    }
    ...
 }
```

So what could be the right way to test such? How to reuse these testMethods? Or maybe I just should not do the reuse for unit testing?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752521/running-the-same-junit-test-case-multiple-time-with-different-data

Comment: @Taylor I don't think that answers this question though, that is to run the same data in one test class, here  what I want to do is to reuse the same test case across two separate test classes

Comment: to be clearer, to reuse the same test methods

Comment: There are examples in there using different objects for the same test.  If you want two test classes to have the same test method, just write a base class and inherit.

Comment: Thanks Taylor! That makes sense. I will close this question and link to the ones that solved my issue.