# How to create parametrized test cases in JUnit 4 and Kotlin for Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit

I need something similar to C# NUnit [TestCase](http://dotnetpattern.com/nunit-testcase-example) scenario with fixed expected results.

I've already found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752521/running-the-same-junit-test-case-multiple-time-with-different-data) on SO which has great solutions but they are for Java only and as suggested in some of the answers I followed [this tutorial](https://springframework.guru/unit-testing-junit-part-4-parameterized-theories/), but simply converting it to Kotlin doesn't work.

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class EmailIdValidatorTest {

    private String emailId;
    private boolean expected;

    public EmailIdValidatorTest(String emailId, boolean expected) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.expected = expected;
    }
    @Parameterized.Parameters(name= "{index}: isValid({0})={1}")
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                        {"mary@testdomain.com", true},
                        {"mary.smith@testdomain.com", true},
                        {"mary_smith123@testdomain.com", true},
                        {"mary@testdomaindotcom", false},
                        {"mary-smith@testdomain", false},
                        {"testdomain.com", false}
                }
        );
    }
    @Test
    public void testIsValidEmailId() throws Exception {
        boolean actual= EmailIdUtility.isValid(emailId);
        assertThat(actual, is(equalTo(expected)));
    }
}
```

So what is the correct way to write Kotlin parametrized unit tests with JUnit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following [this amazing](https://springframework.guru/unit-testing-junit-part-4-parameterized-theories/) tutorial, we can implement it in Kotlin language in this way:

First of all convert the `EmailIdUtility` class into Kotlin:

```
object EmailIdUtility {
    fun isValid(email: String): Boolean {
        val regex =
            "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$"
        val pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)
        val m = pattern.matcher(email)
        return m.matches()
    }
}
```

Then convert the `EmailIdValidatorTest` into Kotlin

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized::class)
class EmailIdValidatorTest(
    private val email: String,
    private val expected: Boolean)
{
    @Test
    fun testIsValidEmailId() {
        val actual = EmailIdUtility.isValid(email)
        assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: isValid({0})={1}")
        fun data(): Iterable<Array<Any>> {
            return arrayListOf(
                arrayOf("mary@testdomain.com", true),
                arrayOf("mary.smith@testdomain.com", true),
                arrayOf("mary_smith123@testdomain.com", true),
                arrayOf("mary@testdomaindotcom", false),
                arrayOf("mary-smith@testdomain", false),
                arrayOf("testdomain.com", false)
            ).toList()
        }
    }
}
```

> Remember to add `@JvmStatic` in the `data()` method, otherwise you will get the error: java.lang.Exception: No public static parameters method on class com.example.testapp.dev.EmailIdValidatorTest

---

**EASIER WAY**

If you can use another library (working in Android too) I suggest you to add [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams) to your test dependencies, in Android it could be:

```
testImplementation  "pl.pragmatists:JUnitParams:1.1.1"
```

Then you could convert the above class in this way:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner::class)
class EmailIdValidatorTest {

    @Test
    @Parameters(value = [
        "mary@testdomain.com, true",
        "mary.smith@testdomain.com, true",
        "mary_smith123@testdomain.com, true",
        "mary@testdomaindotcom, false",
        "mary-smith@testdomain, false",
        "testdomain.com, false"
    ])
    fun testIsValidEmailId(email: String, expected: Boolean) {
        val actual = EmailIdUtility.isValid(email)
        assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }
}
```

which for me is a lot easier than the `JUnit` way.

For more examples on how to use JUnitParams you can check the link.

> With JUnit 5 this is a [lot easier](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests)
>   but currently JUnit 5 is not supported for Android tests if you don't
>   use [Android-JUnit 5](https://github.com/mannodermaus/android-junit5) too.

Comment: @ MatPag this is really nice explanation. can you also suggest how we can create multiple test methods in the same class to run against parameterized data.

Answer (score 8):

I know you're using JUnit 4, but if you consider to update to JUnit 5, you can use `@TestFactory` annotation to execute parametrized unit test.

In your case that would result in a test class like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DynamicTest
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestFactory

internal class EmailIdValidatorTest {

    @TestFactory
    fun `test email id validity`() =
        listOf(
            "mary@testdomain.com" to true,
            "mary.smith@testdomain.com" to true,
            "mary_smith123@testdomain.com" to true,
            "mary@testdomaindotcom" to false,
            "mary-smith@testdomain" to false,
            "testdomain.com" to false
        ).map {
            dynamicTest("email ${it.first} should be ${if (it.second) "valid" else "not valid" }") {
                val actual = EmailIdUtility.isValid(it.first)
                assertEquals(expected, actual)
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: This is a nice addition, thank you (even if currently JUnit 5 is not directly supported on Android)

Comment: This is different from the JUnit way in the sense it either passes or fails on one of the assertions, while JUnit parameterized runs parameters independently